# Adding RadioMenuItem to ToggleGroup in FXML

Tags: javafx, radio-button, menuitem, fxml

Somewhere inside my FXML, I have this:

```
<fx:define>
  <ToggleGroup fx:id="toggleGroup1"/>  
</fx:define>
<Menu fx:id="toggleMyView" text="%MyView">
  <items>
    <RadioMenuItem text="%hide"
                   selected="true"
                   onAction="#handleLoadComponent"
                   toggleGroup="toggleGroup1"/>`
```

Somehow I get the error:

`Unable to coerce toggleGroup1 to class javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup`

But why?

What I'm trying to do is to create a `Menu` containing several of `RadioMenuItem` which are all in the same ToggleGroup. How can I add them to the toggle group in my FXML file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to write

```
toggleGroup="$toggleGroup1"
```

Comment: It also appears to be *important* that your `<fx:define>` block that defines your `ToggleGroup` be **above** any references to said `ToggleGroup`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SceneBuilder then set the field ToggleGroup in properties to the name of the group.